# Querying One to one Relationship

Tags: c#, database, entity

I have to entities, that has one to one relationship.

```
public class Ad
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string desciption { get; set; }

    public SourceAddress SourceAddress { get; set; }
}

public class SourceAddress : IAddress
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public new int StreetNumber { get; set; }

    public new string Route { get; set; }

    public new string City { get; set; }

    public new string State { get; set; }

    public new string PostalCode { get; set; }

    public new string Coutry { get; set; }

    public int AdId { get; set; }

    public virtual Ad Ad { get; set; }
}
```

When I query the entity Ads:

```
Ad add = _db.Ads.FirstOrDefault();   //i am not able to use include
```

All elements are loaded but the SourceAddress is null. How can i fix that

Answer (score 1):

You should use **Include** method to get the data from navigation property:

```
Ad add = _db.Ads.Include(a=>a.SourceAddress).FirstOrDefault();
```